# Termux cool theme custom

Tags: terminal, themes, termux

i want to this feature in my termux bcz it look cool and increase readability.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SYFc.png)

here i marked these with red colour.

In image when user is in home directory it show home directory icon that's look cool.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you were looking for a prompt like the one you showed. I advise you to try zsh, it's another shell than bash, with ohmyzsh, it's something that allows you to manage zsh more easily, and the Powerlevel10k theme, that's what gives you the look you want. With Powerlevel10k, you can choose what you want to see in your prompt, for example where you are, git status, time, etc. To install all of this, you can look at the following GitHub links:
-zsh : [enter link description here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh)

- ohmyzsh : [enter link description here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh)
- Powerlevel10k : [enter link description here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k)

When it's installed, do `p10k configure` and choose what options you want. There you go, I hope this will help you.